# Как в RedBeanPHP правильно написать запрос?

Tags: php, mysql, redbeanphp

Здравствуйте
есть вот такой запрос

```
$section = R::findAll('section', 'name = ?', ['news']);
```

сейчас в запросе достаются все поля.
как отредактировать запрос чтоб вытащить только два поля (id и title)?
прошу помощи кто знаком с данной ORM

Answer (score 1):

```
R::getCol('select title from news');
```

Читайте документацию => http://www.redbeanphp.com/manual3_0/index.php?p=/manual3_0/queries

Там прямо так и написано

> To fetch a single column: